# Django: TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder with user authorization

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am using django for a project and I am trying to let the user access a page if they are authenticated and authorized to perform that action. I have a model called Post and my app is called myblog. I am currently getting the error Django:Could not parse the remainder: '('myblog.add_Post')' from 'user.has_perm('myblog.add_Post')'

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Add Post...
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.has_perm('myblog.add_Post') %}     
<h1>Add A Blog Post</h1>
<br/><br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Post</button> 
</div>
{% else %}
Access Denied!
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

If i remove the "and user.has_perm('myblog.add_Post')" this template works; however, I need to check if the user has permissions.

Comment: Django's template language can not parse method calls and subscription, so `user.has_perm('myblog.add_Post')` will *not* work.

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and perms.myblog.add_Post %}
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions

Answer (score 0):

change

```
user.has_perm('myblog.add_Post')
```

to

> perm.myblog.add_Post